# How to pivot a table into slices based on the content?

Tags: sql, pivot

I’d like to pivot a set of columns based on the value of a specific “master” column.

Let’s say we start with the data in this format:

| refid | planid | planprice | termlength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd-1y | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | abcd-2y | 10 | 2 |
| 1 | abcd-3y | 20 | 3 |
| 2 | xyz-6m | 20 | 0.5 |
| 2 | xyz-1y | 40 | 1 |
| 2 | xyz-3y | 60 | 3 |
| 2 | xyz-5y | 100 | 5 |

I need to perform some kind of pivot somehow, to generate the format:

| refid | planid1 | planid2 | planid3 | planid4 | planprice1 | planprice2 | planprice3 | planprice4 | termlength1 | termlength2 | termlength3 | termlength4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd-1y | abcd-2y | abcd-3y |  | 5 | 10 | 20 |  | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
| 2 | xyz-6m | xyz-1y | xyz-3y | xyz-5y | 20 | 40 | 60 | 100 | 0.5 | 1 | 3 | 5 |

How might we do this? I could imagine an intermediate step involving a table

that has a count that represents “this is the index of the subrow under each refid). And then the max out of this column times number of these columns becomes the amount of extra columns in the final output.

Is there a simple way to do this with sql?

Comment: This sort of thing varies by make and version of table server. Please [edit] your tags to tell us what you use.

Comment: Is there any column that represents the order of columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform rows to columns in several ways, here is a simple one.

Modify your table structure so that it contains only three columns; refID, entryName and entryValue. The entryName column will store the columns headers for the view you want, and the entryValue column will store the values you want to store for specific refId.
Your table should be like this:

[image]

To transfer the data from your table to the new table use the following query, I tried to create a simple one since you will use it only one time.

First, create the new table; `[refId],[entryName]` will be the primary key of the table, then transfer the data using the following query:

```
insert into MyTable 
SELECT [refId],
       concat('planid',ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by refid order by planid))
      ,[planid]  
FROM OldTable union all
SELECT [refId],
       concat('planprice',ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by refid order by planid))
      ,[planprice]  
FROM OldTable union all
SELECT [refId],
       concat('termlength',ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by refid order by planid))
      ,[termlength]  
FROM OldTable
```

To see a sample of the transferred data run the following query:

```
SELECT [refId],
       concat('planid',ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by refid order by planid))
      ,[planid]  
FROM OldTable
```

Now you can use the following query to get exactly what you want.

```
SELECT refid, planid1, planid2, planid3, planid4, planprice1,
planprice2, planprice3, planprice4, termlength1, termlength2, termlength3, termlength4
  FROM 
  (
  select [refId],[entryValue],[entryName] from myTable
  ) T
  PIVOT
  (MAX([entryValue]) for [entryName] in (planid1, planid2,  planid3, planid4, planprice1,
planprice2, planprice3, planprice4, termlength1, termlength2, termlength3, termlength4)) P
order by refid
```

If you want to keep your table without creating another one you can combine the transform query and pivot query into one query as the following; but I don't prefer this in terms of efficiency and future updates on your table i.e. adding new entry such as plan date:

```
SELECT refid, planid1, planid2, planid3, planid4, planprice1,
planprice2, planprice3, planprice4, termlength1, termlength2, termlength3, termlength4
  FROM 
(select * from
(
SELECT [refId],
       concat('planid',ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by refid order by planid)) as entryName
      ,[planid]  as entryValue
FROM OldTable union all
SELECT [refId],
       concat('planprice',ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by refid order by planid)) as entryName
      ,[planprice]   as entryValue
FROM OldTable union all
SELECT [refId],
       concat('termlength',ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by refid order by planid)) as entryName
      ,[termlength]   as entryValue
FROM OldTable) NewTable) T
PIVOT
  (MAX([entryValue]) for [entryName] in (planid1, planid2,  planid3, planid4, planprice1,
planprice2, planprice3, planprice4, termlength1, termlength2, termlength3, termlength4)) P
order by refid
```

I hope that was what you are looking for.

Comment: Is it supposed to be obvious how to transform the starting table into the table you gave in your example??

Comment: From your question, I supposed that your table is full of data and you want to transfer this data to the new table, I updated the answer so it contains now how to transfer your data to the new table.

Comment: By the way, I used MS SQL server database, as O. Jones commented 'This sort of thing varies by make and version of table server'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on SQL flavor, and if `refid` has a finite number of possibilities, something like this would be an option:

---

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `refid` INTEGER,
  `planid` VARCHAR(7),
  `planprice` INTEGER,
  `termlength` FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO t
  (`refid`, `planid`, `planprice`, `termlength`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'abcd-1y', '5', '1'),
  ('1', 'abcd-2y', '10', '2'),
  ('1', 'abcd-3y', '20', '3'),
  ('2', 'xyz-6m', '20', '0.5'),
  ('2', 'xyz-1y', '40', '1'),
  ('2', 'xyz-3y', '60', '3'),
  ('2', 'xyz-5y', '100', '5');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT refid
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(planids, '$[0]') planid1
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(planids, '$[1]') planid2
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(planids, '$[2]') planid3
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(planids, '$[3]') planid4
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(planprices, '$[0]') planprice1
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(planprices, '$[1]') planprice2
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(planprices, '$[2]') planprice3
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(planprices, '$[3]') planprice4
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(termlengths, '$[0]') termlength1
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(termlengths, '$[1]') termlength2
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(termlengths, '$[2]') termlength3
    ,  JSON_EXTRACT(termlengths, '$[3]') termlength4  
FROM (
  SELECT refid
       , JSON_ARRAYAGG(planid) planids
       , JSON_ARRAYAGG(planprice) planprices
       , JSON_ARRAYAGG(termlength) termlengths
  FROM t
  GROUP BY refid) a;
```

| refid | planid1 | planid2 | planid3 | planid4 | planprice1 | planprice2 | planprice3 | planprice4 | termlength1 | termlength2 | termlength3 | termlength4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "abcd-1y" | "abcd-2y" | "abcd-3y" |  | 5 | 10 | 20 |  | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |  |
| 2 | "xyz-6m" | "xyz-1y" | "xyz-3y" | "xyz-5y" | 20 | 40 | 60 | 100 | 0.5 | 1.0 | 3.0 | 5.0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bzbH1EgCTJGRubVaNie76M/0)